# ERROR : NOT SUPPORT DVFS LOCK android application

Tags: android, android-debug

After stating my android application on galaxy s2 phone, I get following error :

**ERROR : NOT SUPPORT DVFS LOCK**

I googled for this issue but i didn't find anything to solve this kind of issue.

So i need your help. Is there anyone who can guide me for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap/+/11038e7ec6b415b28f95cd7526be72ee6b8d4607/arch/arm/mach-omap2/dvfs.c :

> DVFS is a technique that uses the optimal operating frequency and
>   voltage to  * allow a task to be performed in the required amount of
>   time.  * OMAP processors have voltage domains whose voltage can be
>   scaled to  * various levels depending on which the operating
>   frequencies of certain  * devices belonging to the domain will also
>   need to be scaled. This voltage  * frequency tuple is known as
>   Operating Performance Point (OPP). A device  * can have multiple
>   OPP's. Also a voltage domain could be shared between  * multiple
>   devices. Also there could be dependencies between various  * voltage
>   domains for maintaining system performance like VDD  * should be at
>   voltage v1 when VDD is at voltage v2.  *  * The design of this
>   framework takes into account all the above mentioned  * points. To
>   summarize the basic design of DVFS framework:-  *  * 1. Have device
>   opp tables for each device whose operating frequency can be  *
>   scaled. This is easy now due to the existance of hwmod layer which  * 
>   allow storing of device specific info. The device opp tables contain 
>   *    the opp pairs (frequency voltage tuples), the voltage domain pointer  *    to which the device belongs to, the device specific
>   set_rate and  *    get_rate API's which will do the actual scaling of
>   the device frequency  *    and retrieve the current device frequency. 
>   * 2. Introduce use counting on a per VDD basis. This is to take care multiple  *    requests to scale a VDD. The VDD will be scaled to the
>   maximum of the  *    voltages requested.  * 3. Keep track of all
>   scalable devices belonging to a particular voltage  *    domain the
>   voltage layer.  * 4. Keep track of frequency requests for each of the
>   device. This will enable  *    to scale individual devices to
>   different frequency (even w/o scaling  *    voltage aka frequency
>   throttling)  * 5. Generic dvfs API that can be called by anybody to
>   scale a device opp.  *    This API takes the device pointer and
>   frequency to which the device  *    needs to be scaled to. This API
>   then internally finds out the voltage  *    domain to which the device
>   belongs to and the voltage to which the voltage  *    domain needs to
>   be put to for the device to be scaled to the new frequency  *    from
>   the device opp table. Then this API will add requested frequency into 
>   *    the corresponding target device frequency list and add voltage request to  *    the corresponding vdd. Subsequently it calls voltage
>   scale function which  *    will find out the highest requested voltage
>   for the given vdd and scales  *    the voltage to the required one and
>   also adds corresponding frequency  *    request for that voltage. It
>   also runs through the list of all  *    scalable devices belonging to
>   this voltage domain and scale them to the  *    appropriate
>   frequencies using the set_rate pointer in the device opp  *    tables.
>   * 6. Handle inter VDD dependecies. This will take care of scaling domain's voltage  *    and frequency together.  *  *  * DOC: The Core
>   DVFS data structure:  * ==================================  * 
>   Structure Name                   Example Tree  *  ---------  *    /|\ 
>   +-------------------+      +-------------------+  *     |          |User2 (dev2, freq2)+---\  |User4 (dev4, freq4)+---\  *     |
>   +-------------------+   |  +-------------------+   |  * (struct omap_dev_user_list)            |                          |  *     |
>   +-------------------+   |  +-------------------+   |  *     |          |User1 (dev1, freq1)+---|  |User3 (dev3, freq3)+---|  *    \|/
>   +-------------------+   |  +-------------------+   |  *  ---------                             |                          |  *    /|\
>   +------------+------+   +---------------+--+  *     |                     | DEV1 (dev,        |   | DEV2 (dev)       |  * (struct
>   omap_vdd_dev_list)|omap_dev_user_list)|   |omap_dev_user_list|  *
>   |                     +------------+------+   +--+---------------+  * 
>   \|/           /|\             /-----+-------------+------> others..  *
>   ---------    Frequency          |  *    /|\                        +--+------------------+  *     |                         |       VDD_n         |  *     |                         | (omap_vdd_dev_list, |  * (struct
>   omap_vdd_dvfs_info)** | omap_vdd_user_list) |  *     |
>   +--+------------------+  *     |                            |   (ROOT NODE: omap_dvfs_info_list)  *    \|/                           |  * 
>   ---------    Voltage            ---+-------------+----------> others..  *    /|\          \|/          +-------+----+ 
>   +-----+--------+  *     |                        |  vdd_user2 |  |   vdd_user3  |  * (struct omap_vdd_user_list)  | (dev, volt)|  | (dev,
>   volt)  |  *    \|/                       +------------+ 
>   +--------------+  *  ---------  * Key: ** -> Root of the tree.  * NOTE: we use the priority to store the voltage/frequency  *  * For
>   voltage dependency description, see: struct dependency:  *
>   voltagedomain -> (description of the voltagedomain)  *
>   omap_vdd_info -> (vdd information)  *
>   omap_vdd_dep_info[]-> (stores array of depedency info)  *
>   omap_vdd_dep_volt[] -> (stores array of maps)  *
>   (main_volt -> dep_volt) (a singular map)  */

That means that if your phone doesn't support it, your application will not run on it. I think there is no other way.

Comment: "DVFS is a technique that uses the optimal operating frequency and voltage to * allow a task to be performed in the required amount of time." - maybe you're using a feature which use that kernel function ?

Comment: But i dont use kernal function within my android application. Is there any otherway it may occur ?